# PythonAnywhere giving "FileNotFoundError" even though I am using absolute path to ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere, absolute-path

I got the following code on PythonAnywhere:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_driver = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input"))).send_keys("directions 3406 north seminary ave to 933 robinhood lane")
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.FPdoLc.lJ9FBc > center > input.gNO89b"))).click()
value = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#exp0 > div.mGSxre.Ra9ql > div > div"))).text
print(value)
```

I am referencing the absolute path and the code will work when I run it on PyCharm. I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rossleavitt/C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe'`
and while handling that error I get `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`. What's happening here? Do I need to upgrade my PythonAnywhere account?

Ross

Comment: it's failing to find chromedriver.exe in the path you provided so it falls back to the "PATH" system/environment variable.  (which isn't set)  I would axe the "os.path.abspath" part... just pass it the path.  (and use backslashes for Windows)  Right now that os.path method is adding "/home/..." as if it were on Linux.

Comment: I tried taking out the os.path.abspath part and so I got the following: `chrome_driver = "C:\Users\ross\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)`. Still didn't work. Is that what you meant by just passing the path?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clearly with `os.path.abspath('C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')` line.
As can be seen it returns `/home/rossleavitt/C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe` that is not appears to be a valid path to the `chromedriver.exe` file
As I see from the `os.path.abspath` output which is `/home/rossleavitt/` you are working on Linux machine.
If so it is impossible that `chromedriver.exe` is located by this path `C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe`.
So it's a messy mix of Linux and Windows paths together.
If I understand correctly how `os.path.abspath` works, if you want to use you `os.path.abspath` you should add the path to `chromedriver.exe` file to the system PATH.
Then you can use it simply as `os.path.abspath(chromedriver.exe)` and it will return the absolute path to `chromedriver.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

The path to chromedriver on PythonAnywhere is `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` but you do not need it, as `/usr/local/bin/` is in `$PATH`

Chromedriver on Linux is not `chromedriver.exe` but just `chromedriver`.

To use Chrome on Python anywhere you need to upgrade selenium. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/